# auth_key generation failed 5 time(s)

Tags: python, telethon, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm unable to connect to Telegram using Telethon.

```
client = TelegramClient('sessions/'+api_hash, api_id, api_hash)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

client.start()
```

See the log bellow.

```
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to
149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull... DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 1... DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection success! DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:New auth_key attempt 1... WARNING:telethon.network.connection.connection:Server closed the connection: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired WARNING:telethon.network.connection.connection:Server closed the connection: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection error 1 during auth_key gen: OSError: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired INFO:telethon.network.connection.connection:<class 'OSError'> during disconnect: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired INFO:telethon.network.connection.connection:<class 'OSError'> during disconnect: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 2... DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection success! DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:New auth_key attempt 2... WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection error 2 during auth_key gen: OSError: [WinError 121] The semaphore timeout period has expired DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection attempt 3... DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection success! DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:New auth_key attempt 3... WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 3 at new auth_key failed: Step 1 invalid nonce from server DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:New auth_key attempt 4... WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 4 at new auth_key failed: Step 1 invalid nonce from server DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:New auth_key attempt 5... WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 5 at new auth_key failed: Step 1 invalid nonce from server DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:New auth_key attempt 6... WARNING:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Attempt 6 at new auth_key failed: Step 1 invalid nonce from server INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Disconnecting from
149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull... DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Closing current connection... DEBUG:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Cancelling 0 pending message(s)... INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Disconnection from
149.154.167.51:443/TcpFull complete! Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\python\2024\m.py", line 13, in <module>     client.start()   File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 128, in start     else self.loop.run_until_complete(coro)   File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 641, in run_until_complete     return future.result()   File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\auth.py", line 135, in _start     await self.connect()   File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\client\telegrambaseclient.py", line 538, in connect     if not await self._sender.connect(self._connection(   File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 132, in connect     await self._connect()   File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 262, in _connect     raise e ConnectionError: auth_key generation failed 5 time(s)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the wrong key or you don't have a key.
Please amend your question according to the guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That log is not readable in one line

Comment: ok see now @julaine